# Capitalized non-Unicode URL doesn't work

Tags: url, case-sensitive, url-encoding

I've non-Unicode URLs like this:

http://allabout-school.com/%d8%af%d9%84%d9%8a%d9%84-%d8%a7%d9%84%d9%85%d8%af%d8%a7%d8%b1%d8%b3/%d9%85%d8%af%d8%a7%d8%b1%d8%b3-%d9%86%d8%ac%d8%af-%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%a3%d9%87%d9%84%d9%8a%d8%a9-2/

When I click the link it opens correctly, but for some unknown reason it's sometimes converted to capital letters, and after this it doesn't work! This is an example:

http://allabout-school.com/%D8%AF%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%84-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B3/%D9%85%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B3-%D9%86%D8%AC%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D9%87%D9%84%D9%8A%D8%A9-2/

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why is that a problem? %d8 is the same as %D8. If you hover over both urls you'll see in the status bar that they are the same.

Comment: I don't know! Moreover, sometimes when I open a link by clicking it, it opens correctly, but when I select the same URL in the address bar and press Enter it doesn't open!

Comment: @saitho: "*%d8 is the same as %D8*" - logically yes, url encoding is supposed to be case-insensitive, and url decoding is supposed to be applied before processing the path. But some web servers don't follow the rules, and this server is one of them. Clicking on the two links in the question produce identical HTTP requests other than the case of the characters in the path. The first link works, the second link doesn't. Changing the case of only certain characters in the first link does cause a breakage (eg, changing the first `%d8` to `%D8` breaks, but changing the last `%a9`  to `%A9` doesn't)

Comment: @Behiry: this is a server-side problem, nothing you can fix on the client side. Contact the server admin and let them know that their server's handling of encoded URLs is buggy.